# Printing out lists within dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Noobish question here. Haven't done too much python in my day. I'm having an issue with cycling through a dictionary and printing out the key as well as the value(lists in this case) in this format:

```
deer : brown antlers doe fawn
bear : black teeth polar cub
```

It is currently outputing like this

```
('deer:', ['brown', 'antlers', 'doe', 'fawn'])
('bear:', ['black', 'teeth', 'polar', 'cub'])
```

My code is:

```
animals = {'deer': ['brown', 'antlers', 'doe', 'fawn'],
           'bear': ['black', 'teeth', 'polar', 'cub']}

for i in animals:
    print(i +':', animals[i])
```

Obviously it's the syntax of my loop, but after an hour of failures, I'm not sure what is going on. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs on the python website? Or reading a short tutorial /watching a short tutorial on python? Beginner python tutorials should cover everything you need to know.

Comment: @Julien read his question, he said that the current output is not what he wants, not that its not correct.

Comment: @CharlesAddis Thanks for the suggestion, Charles, will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
animals = {'deer': ['brown', 'antlers', 'doe', 'fawn'],
           'bear': ['black', 'teeth', 'polar' 'cub']}

for i in animals:
    print i +':', ' '.join(animals[i]) # add ( ) for python3...
```

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is missing the fact that in Python, if you want both the key and value, it is better to iterate over the "items".

```
animals = {'deer': ['brown', 'antlers', 'doe', 'fawn'],
           'bear': ['black', 'teeth', 'polar', 'cub']}

for animal_name, animal_list in animals.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(
            animal_name,
            " ".join(animal_list),
            ))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
animals = {'deer': ['brown', 'antlers', 'doe', 'fawn'],
           'bear': ['black', 'teeth', 'polar', 'cub']}


for k, v in animals.items():
    print "%s:%s" % (k, " ".join(str(i) for i in v))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would highly suggest you read/watch some beginner python tutorials. Derek Banas has some good videos on youtube which may help. The problem is that you're attempting to print the entire list, not the individual elements of it (calling list.**str**). Assuming you have experience with other programming languages, it should be no surprise to you that python strings have a join method which accept an iterable. What you're wishing to do, is something like this:

```
# using a format string
for key in dict_of_lists:
    print('{} : {}'.format(key, ' '.join(dict_of_lists[key]))
```